# What permission that PAT needs to run GetCommitsAsync?

Tags: git, rest, permissions, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

My code is going to call both `GetCommitAsync` and `GetCommitsAsync` using service account PAT with permission `vso.build,vso.release`, `vso.code_write`, `vso.project`, `vso.taskgroups_read` ,`vso.work`.

But in our case is that:

1. `GetCommitAsync` returns commit as expected, but `GetCommitsAsync` returns nothing without exception
2. Both `GetCommitAsync` and `GetCommitsAsync` returns commit(s) as expected when trying my PAT with permission `code_read`.

Can anyone help answering what could the reason we got this?

Comment: Could you please share your simple code sample here? I test with the diiferent permission PAT, and I don't get the error. So I think maybe we can get more information in your code.

Comment: Thank you for helping on this, it seems because I did not provide time zone information when setting FromDate and ToDate in GitQueryCommitsCriteria, in this case, vsts would use the time zone set in vsts account profile.